# GDirections equivalent object in Google Maps V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I've been searching in Google Documentation about an equivalent object of GDirections Api V2. I found DirectionsRenderer but it doesn't have the method I need, which is 
`GDirections.Load("from:some Lat, some Lng to: some Lat, some Lng")`.

Does anybody knows an equivalent Object or Method in Api V3?

Answer (score 0):

See this example in the documentation:
https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple

Replace start and end with your desired coordinates (or with a google.maps.LatLng containing those coordinates).

Directions with waypoints:
https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints

Comment: I think you didn't get it. I have an array of all my route LatLngs, not only the start and end LatLngs. In V2 I could simple insert these points into this function (load) and the map draw a route trough these points.

Comment: 1. Where did you indicate that in your question? 2. The v2 API doesn't support an arbitrary list of waypoints either (but does allow more).  3. If you want waypoints, see that example in the documentation.

Comment: Sorry about the question! I already have the points, at least I think I do. All I want to do is create a route, drag it, save it, open it later and be able to edit it. I tried at least 5 ways to do it. I tried to serialize and de-serialize the response object, save in BD. Tried to save the LatLngs that exists in overview_path...Then I found that function in V2 that is possible parse the LatLngs and it route in the map. About my problema, do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @Daniel: I suggest you edit the question to make it complete. Include the most successful code you've tried. Stack Overflow is for specific coding problems. (You could edit the typo in the title too)